# HP SAS hdd in non-HP server

Tags: storage, hard-drive, hp, sas

I wonder if I could re-use some HP SAS drive in a non-HP server.

```
Description:
146GB 2.5" Serial Attached SCSI (SAS) SFF
3G Single Port Hot-Plug 10K HDD
Option Part# 431958-B21
Spare Part# 432320-001
Assembly Part# 431954-003
Model# DG146ABAB4
```

Is this just a regular SAS disk? 
Is there a specific model fromn HP that is known to work?

Answer (score 7):

The HP disk you're referring to is a [Seagate SAS drive](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=6816af4bb4bed010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD&locale=en-US) with HP firmware. 

The Seagate equivalent is the [Savvio 10K.2 - Model ST9146802SS](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=6816af4bb4bed010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD&locale=en-US).

There's nothing that would preclude you from using it elsewhere in non-HP equipment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason it wouldn't work. Give it a try - no harm can be done.

Answer (score 2):

It will work. HP actually outsources hard drive production and just flashes them with HP firmware and rebrands them. Most of the hard drives work in other servers provided they are not the "specialized" type which contains another firmware which only recognizes HP servers.